# Smoothing animation loop

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I have an animation and i'm trying to make it loop perfectly, but you can clearly see the "jump" from the last to the first frame. My last and first frame are exactly the same, and i tried to set to the last framse -1 but you still can see the jump. I'm doing it in 30fps and i don't know how to fix this.

I've read about the graphe editor but i don't understand anything in there... Here's a pic of my graph

[image]

What do i have to do here? It's not very readable as a graph. I've clicked normalize to get this view, cause with normalize unchecked it's even worse

EDIT: Forget it please, i actually changed my starting position.

For those animating a tail. If it's a waving tail, you need to start with tail set to the most left/right position and end in the same position. My mistake was that i start with my tail in the middle.

Comment: any .blend file you can attach with the question so we can take alook at the problem without assumptions? Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload a simplified version of your .blend file.

Comment: @hawkenfox I don't think giving everyone my blend file is a good idea

Comment: Then it's your call , problems get solved much faster that way. With text there is not much to go on. It would help to see the animation in action along with the curve.

Comment: You can delete the files content and just represent a simple .blend and thats how most of use do it anyways. No need to pass on the whole project file to someone if you don't have to.